# Javascript: open URL after a loop gives a right answer

Tags: javascript, while-loop, do-while

I can't figure this out:

```
var right = {"Google" :1, "Bing" :1}

        do {
            var website = prompt("Where should I redirect you: Google, Yahoo!, ebay or CCSF?", "");         
        } while (!right[website]);

        if (website == "Google") {
            var url = "https://www.google.com/";
            window.location(url, '_blank');
            window.focus();
        } else if (website == "Bing") {
            var url = "http://www.bing.com/";
            window.location(url, '_blank');
            window.focus();
        } else {
            ;
        }
```

The loop supposed to keep a person until he types in the right word (Google or Bing in my example). However, next function to open this url fails to work. (I don't want to use select/option). Also, end "else" looks suspicious to me too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`window.location` is not a function.  You mean to use `window.open`.

Comment: Great! It is that simple :) thank you. It open me a new window instead of new tab though ...

Comment: Try without the `_blank`, but this also depends on browser settings

Answer (score 0):

You should user something like:

```
window.open( url );
```

or

```
location.href = url;
```